# How to insert fields extracted from XML in one table into another table?

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have one table (say `messages`) with `primary_key` and `xml_data`. I know how to extract several values from one `xml_data` value, like this:

```
DECLARE @x XML = 'the XML value'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    'http://somenamespace/document' AS msg,
    'http://somenamespace/externalMessage' AS dat
)
SELECT c.value('(dat:delivery_list/dat:identifier)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS dl_identifier,
       c.value('(dat:created_on)[1]', 'datetime2(0)') AS created_on,
       c.value('(dat:delivery_list/dat:shipping_date)[1]', 'datetime2(0)') AS shipping_date
FROM @x.nodes('/msg:data/msg:body/msg:request/msg:data/dat:operation/dat:data/dat:external_message') AS t(c)
```

Now, I want to build another table (say `heads`), with the same `primary_key` and with the columns `dl_identifier`, `created_on`, and `shipping_date` filled with the extracted information from the `messages.xml_data`. It should process only the `messages.xml_data` that are new (no extraction was done, yet).

So far, I was thinking about left-outer joining the tables to detect the missing `heads` records like this:

```
SELECT m.primary_key,
       m.xml_data
  FROM messages AS m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN heads AS h
            ON h.primary_key = m.primary_key
               AND m.xml_data IS NOT NULL
 WHERE h.primary_key IS NULL
```

It selects the wanted `m.xml_data`. Is it possible to insert the values extracted from the `m.xml_data` (and with the `primary_key`) into `heads` without using a cursor?

Comment: Do the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#OtherTables) for `insert ... select ...` not meet your needs?

Comment: Aside: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: @HABO: Yes, this is for MS SQL Server 2014 Standard (12.0.5000.0). What I do not know is how to pass te `m.xml_data` into the upper SELECT for extracting the values, and inserting it to the other table -- for each record of the `m`. I know how to do it with a cursor. However, I do not know whether it is possible without a cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help most to provide an MCVE. Look at the following example:

```sql
--a mockup table to simulate your messages
DECLARE @tblMessages TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
--I insert 4 messages
INSERT INTO @tblMessages VALUES ('<root><test a="test 1.1" /><test a="test 1.2" /></root>')
                               ,('<root><test a="test 2.1" /><test a="test 2.2" /></root>')
                               ,('<root><test a="test 3.1" /></root>')
                               ,('<root><test a="test 4.1" /><test a="test 4.2" /><test a="test 4.3" /></root>');

--a mockup table to simulate your "heads" table
DECLARE @tblExtractedValues TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY 
                                 ,message_ID INT NOT NULL /*always use names constaints and you might add FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES messages(primary_key)*/
                                 ,ExtractedValue_test VARCHAR(100));
--Let's simulate, that messages 1 and 3 are extracted already
INSERT INTO @tblExtractedValues VALUES(1,'test 1.1')
                                     ,(1,'test 1.2')
                                     ,(3,'test 3.1');
```

--This statement will read the values out of the XML in "messages", 
--but will omit those with an ID existing in the other table
--You can out-comment the line with `INSERT` to see the SELECT's result

```sql
INSERT INTO @tblExtractedValues(message_ID,ExtractedValue_test)                                  
SELECT m.ID
      ,t.value('@a','varchar(100)')
FROM @tblMessages m
CROSS APPLY m.xml_data.nodes('/root/test') A(t)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM @tblExtractedValues ev
                 WHERE ev.message_ID=m.ID);

--Look at the order of insertion. 1 and 3 have lower IDs than 2 and 4
SELECT * FROM @tblExtractedValues;
```

Comment: Shnugo, thank you for the excellent answer. Sorry for not providing a MCVE. I had to cut the question from the bigger thing, and I did not exactly know what I want. :)